# Supremum of a set of rationals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

My question reads:

Let $a<b$ be real numbers and let the set $T$= $\mathbb{Q}$ $\cap$ $[a,b]$.  Prove $sup T=b$.

My work so far:

(Showing $b$ is an upper bound). Let $y\in\ T$. Then $y\in\ [a,b]$ since the intersection of the rationals and an interval between two real numbers is just said interval. Then, $y\leq\ b$ which shows $b$ is an upper bound.

(Showing least upper bound-Proof by Contradiction)
Let $w\in\ T$ and suppose $w< b$. Then by density, there exists an $x$ such that $b<x<w$.

Here is where I get stuck. I am not too sure how to continue with density here to arrive at a contradiction. I think I am on the right track, but I am missing a step somewhere here.

Comment: I rephrased the title; "Proving a supremum" makes no sense. (You prove a statement, not a number.)

Comment: I think you are thinking too hard about $T=\mathbb Q \cap [a,b]$.  It's easier to just think of: $T$ is all the set of all rational numbers $q$ so that $a \le q \le b$.  The rest should be obvious.  All such $q \le b$ so $b$ is upperbound.  If $w < b$ then there is a $q$ so that $a\le \min(w,a) < q < b$ by the density of the rationals.  So $w$ is not an upper bound.  So $w$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: You have an erroneously reversed inequality: If $b>w\in T$ then there exists an $x\in \mathbb Q$ with $w<x<b$ (NOT $b<x<w$).... So since $w\in T$ implies $w\geq a,$ you have $a<x<b$ and $x\in \mathbb Q$ so $x\in T.$... Hence $w\ne \sup T$ because  $w <x\in T.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I was trying to do a proof by contradiction which is why I have the reversed inequality.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I wanted to use a proof by contradiction for the last portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proof-verification`

> (Showing $b$ is an upper bound `of the set T`). Let $y\in\ T$. Then $y\in\ [a,b]$ since the intersection of the rationals and an interval between two real numbers is just said interval. `[I don't know what you are trying to say in this sentence. b is an upper bound of the set T simply because T is a subset of the interval [a,b]. ]` Then, $y\leq\ b$ which shows $b$ is an upper bound `of the set T`.
>
> (Showing least upper bound-Proof by Contradiction)
>   Let $w\in\ T$ and suppose $w< b$. `[This is not the correct way to prove by contradiction. Your argument breaks down from here.]` Then by density, there exists an $x$ such that $b<x<w$. `[This does not make sense after you assume that b is larger than w.]`
>
> Here is where I get stuck. I am not too sure how to continue with density here to arrive at a contradiction. I think I am on the right track, but I am missing a step somewhere here.

---

To fix the second step, assume instead, $b$ is not a strict upper of $T$, namely there exists a real number $c<b$ such that $c$ is an upper bound "of the set $T$" (one should not miss this phrase!). Now try to see what contradiction you can get.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my improved proof if I post it here?

Comment: @Sam: you could update your post by adding your new proof under the old one.

Comment: Hopefully, it makes more sense now.

Comment: @sam: some phrases are redundant though, the updated proof looks good.

Comment: Thank you! I will go over it and clear up some of the repeats then. I think I just like to reiterate what was said over and over, which is what I need to work on. Does my contradiction now work in this proof?

Comment: @sam: You are welcome. I think so.

Comment: Okay, I will just clean up the proof then!

Answer (score 2):

When you're showing that $b$ is an upper bound, $T\subset [a,b],$ so if $y\in T,$ then $y\in[a,b],$ and therefore $y\leq b.$ Your statement ("the intersection of the rationals and an interval between two real numbers is just said interval") is false, since for example $[\pi,2\pi]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ cannot contain the endpoints $\pi$ and $2\pi$.

When you are showing that $b$ is the least upper bound, you should not assume that $w\in T.$ For example, the supremum of the set $(0,1)$ is $1,$ but $1\not\in (0,1),$ so you should only be assuming that $w$ is an upper bound for $T$, and $w<b.$ As you said, by density, there is a $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $w<x<b,$ since $(w,b)$ is an open interval and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense. But since $x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]=T,$ $w$ cannot be an upper bound for $T$. This contradiction proves that $b$ is in fact the least upper bound for $T$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Okay, I see what I did wrong at the top. Then I cannot simply say $y\in\ [a,b]$ ? Also, I see what I did wrong in the second part of the proof by placing $w\in T$ . I think that is what I was trying to get to, but I did not how to say it correctly that I wanted to pick another upper bound for the set T.

Comment: Sure you can, I'm just saying that it follows because $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$ are true for any sets $A$ and $B$, rather than any property of the real or rational numbers.

Comment: How then is $x\in\ T$ ? Is this because $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and T contains the rationals?

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ by assumption, and $a\leq x\leq b,$ so $x\in[a,b].$ $x\in T$ then follows by definition of intersection. To be careful, we should assume $x\geq a,$ but either $a\leq w<x,$ or $w<a$ and instead of selecting $x\in (w,b)\cap\mathbb{Q},$ we specify that $x\in(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}\subseteq(w,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: "How then is x∈ T ? Is this because x∈Q and T contains the rationals?"  Almost. Let $w < b$.  $w$ may or may be rational. Then by the density *of the rationals* we can find a *rational* $x$ so that $w < x < b$.  Is $x$ in T.  Well, there are 3) things that must happen to make $x\in T$.  1) x is rational.  Check, it is.  2) x <= b.  Check, it is.  3) x >= a.  Um.. can we choose our $w$ to make that happen?

Comment: @fleablood can we choose $w$ such that it is greater than or equal to $a$?

Comment: You know you can!

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Yes, by assumption x∈Q, but how to we go to saying a≤x≤b? Does this come from the fact that a<b?

Comment: Actually, it was my mistake.  You did so in the begining when you assumed that w $\in T$.  I didn't catch that though.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, sorry I meant to say we could $w$ be such that it is greater than or equal to a. I am just wonder where the fact of a<b comes in. Is this saying a, b are rational numbers or that the numbers in between are rationals?

Comment: @fleablood Yes, but then I was told picking $w$ in T might not be best. So, I would then have to make sure I mention w greater than or equal to a.

Comment: You have to rely on the fact that given and $x < y;x,y \in mathbb R$ there will exists a $q\in \mathbb Q$ so that $x < q < y$.  So if $w$ is *anything* so that $a < w < b$ then we can find a *rational* $q$ so that $a < w < q < b$.  So $q \in T$ and $w$ is not an upper bound.  So $b$ is the *least* upper bound.  We *do* have to assume that given any two *real* $x<y$ we can find a *rational* $x < q < y$.  But we *can* assume that.  That is what is call Q being dense in R.

Comment: To prove that $b$ is the least upper bound you have to prove that anything less is *not* an upper bound.  If we pick $w \in T$ then that only proves that $w \in T$ is not an upper bound.  It doesn't prove that *everything* else isn't an upper bound either.

Comment: Right, to get $x\in T,$ we need $a\leq x\leq b,$ and $x\in \mathbb{Q}.$ What I'm saying is that it doesn't matter whether or not $w<a$ or $a\leq w,$ because in either case, we get to choose our $x$ to be a rational in the interval $(w,b)$ such that $a\leq x:$ when $a\leq w,$ choosing $x\in(w,b)$ guarantees $a\leq x,$ and when $w<a,$ we have $a<b,$ so choosing a rational $x\in(a,b)$ implies that $x\in(w,b)$, too.

Comment: Also, the theorem doesn't hold if $a=b,$ since we could take $a=b=\pi,$ in which case $T=\varnothing,$ so its supremum is $-\infty<b.$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are thinking too hard about $T=\mathbb Q∩[a,b]$.

It's easier to just think of: $T$ is all the set of all rational numbers $q$ so that $a≤q≤b$.

The rest should now be obvious.

All such $q≤b$, so $b$ is an upper bound of $T$.

If $a< w<b$ (the density of the reals)  then, (by the density of the rationals within the reals), there is a rational $q$ so that $a< w<q<b$.

So $w$ is not an upper bound of $T$.

So $b$ is the least upper bound of $T$.

=====

**The Density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$.** Lemma: for any $x,y \in \mathbb R$ such that $x < y$ then there exists a $q \in Q$ so that $x < q < y$.

Pf:  Okay, I'm doing this off the top of my head.  It's probably already been proven in your text. But...

Let $w = \frac {x+y}2 \in \mathbb R$.  Then $x < w < y$.  By the definition of the reals there is a sequence of rational $\{q_n\}\to w$.  Thus or any $\epsilon > 0$ there are $q_i$ so that $|w -q_i|< \epsilon$.  If we let $\epsilon < \frac {y-x}2$ then we have $x < w - \epsilon < w < w+ \epsilon < y$.  And also have $w - \epsilon < q_i < w+ \epsilon$.  So $ x < w -\epsilon < q_i < w+ \epsilon < y$.  QED.

Okay, maybe that was overkill for me to prove, but it should be a basic fact you know.

======

Addendum

Definition (I) of Least Upper Bound.

For a set $S$. $w$ is the least upper bound if i )for all $s\in S$ we have $s < w$. (i.e. $w$ is an upper bound.)

ii) if $v$ is an upper bound of $S$ then $w \le v$.

Definition (II) of Least Upper Bound.

For a set $S$. $w$ is the least upper bound if i )for all $s\in S$ we have $s < w$. (i.e. $w$ is an upper bound.)

ii) if $z < w$ then $z$ is not an upper bound.

Both of these definition are the same.

I $\implies$ II:  If $w = \sup S$ and $z < w$.  Then $z \not \ge w$  So $z$ is not upper bound.

II $\implies$ I: If $w = \sup S$ and $v$ is an upper bound then $v \not < w$ so $v\ge w$.

So if I were to do the proof using Definition  I instead of definition II I'd say.

$b$ is an upper bound of $T$.  Let $v$ be an upper bound $T$ as well. There is a rational $q$ so that $a < q < b$ so $q \in T$.  So $a< q \le v$ and $v > a$.  If $a < v < b$ then there are is a rational $r$ so that $a< v < r < b$.  So $r$ is in $T$.  So $v$ is not an upper bound with is a contradiction.  So $v \ge b$.  So $b$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: I see what you are doing with "If a<w<b (the density of the reals) then, (by the density of the rationals within the reals), there is a rational q so that a<w<q<b" however, how does this give us b is a least upper bound? Is this not just showing w is not an upper bound?

Comment: The definition of *least* upper bound is that for any real number $w < b$ then $w$ *isn't* an upper bound.  As $w$ was i) arbitrary and ii) not an upper bound, we know that *any* $w < b$ that $w$ will not be an upper bound.  So that means $b$ is the least possible upper bound.

Comment: Is the definition of least upper bound not if say a is an upper bound and b is an upper bound then $a\leq\ b$ means a is a least upper bound?

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent.  I'll give an alternative.

Comment: Okay, because I was trying to do my proof using contradiction to say b is a least upper bound. Then, is picking $w\in\ T$ okay to start with because I was given a comment that $w$ does not need to be in T.

Comment: So if $b$ is not the least upper bound there is n upper bound $v < b$.  But there is a rational $q$ so that $v < q < b$  which is a contradiction.  If $q \ge a$ then $q$ is in $T$ and $v$ in not an upper bound.  If $q < a$ then $v <a$ and all $r \in T$ are greater than $v$ so $v$ most certainly is not an upper bound.  So if $v$ is an upper it must be $v \ge b$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $b$ is the least upper bound, suppose the contrary, that is, suppose there is another upper bound $w$ such that $w \lt b$ and try to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

in your first part, showing b is an upper bound, your proof is valid. then to show that b is the supremum, proof by contradiction can be as follows:

let c $\in \Re$ be an upper bound of T, assume c<b.

since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Re$, there exist q $\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that q $\in (c,b) \Rightarrow$ c<q<b. then q $\in$ T. then c is not an upperbound, hence a contradiction is reached. therefore b is the supremum.

the same approach also works for proofing supremum for an open interval T=$\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$

note that provided b $\in \Re$, b can be an irrational number.